Plotly Dash Creating Interactive Graph dropdowns
I want to use plotly dash for create interactive graph with two different dropdowns. These dropdowns filter my dataframe for two different columns. However, when I run this code plotly brings empty graph.
app = dash.Dash(__name__)


kanal_options = [{'label': kanal, 'value': kanal} for kanal in df['KNL_TIP_ACK'].unique()]
segment_options = [{'label': segment, 'value': segment} for segment in 
df['Calculation'].unique()]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Login Counts'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
        id='kanal-dropdown',
        options=kanal_options,
        value='SMART',
        clearable=False,
        searchable=False
        ),
        
        dcc.Dropdown(
        id='segment-dropdown', 
        options=segment_options,
        value='MC',
        clearable=False,
        searchable=False
        ),
    ]),
    dcc.Graph(id='bar-chart')
 ])

 @callback(
    Output('bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input('segment-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('kanal-dropdown','value')]
)


def update_bar_chart(selected_kanal, selected_segment):
    filtered_df = df[(df['KNL_TIP_ACK'] == selected_kanal) & (df['Calculation'] == 
  selected_segment)]
    fig = px.bar(filtered_df, x='Açıklama', y='Ortalama Login')

    return fig



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8057) # or whatever you choose
    #app.run(jupyter_mode="tab")



You had it almost right. Here is a version of your app in a Jupyter notebook, but it should work exactly in the same manner in any other IDE.
import pandas as pd
import dash 
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px

data = {
    'KNL_TIP_ACK': ['SMART', 'MANUAL', 'SMART', 'AUTO', 'MANUAL', 'AUTO', 'SMART'],
    'Calculation': ['MC', 'MC', 'SC', 'MC', 'SC', 'MC', 'SC'],
    'Açıklama': ['Description 1', 'Description 2', 'Description 3', 'Description 4', 'Description 5', 'Description 6', 'Description 7'],
    'Ortalama Login': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

kanal_options = [{'label': kanal, 'value': kanal} for kanal in df['KNL_TIP_ACK'].unique()]
segment_options = [{'label': segment, 'value': segment} for segment in df['Calculation'].unique()]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Dynamic Plotly Graph with Dropdowns'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='kanal-dropdown',
        options=kanal_options,
        value='SMART',  
        clearable=False,
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='segment-dropdown',
        options=segment_options,
        value='MC',  
        clearable=False,
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='bar-chart')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input('kanal-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('segment-dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_bar_chart(selected_kanal, selected_segment):
    filtered_df = df[(df['KNL_TIP_ACK'] == selected_kanal) & (df['Calculation'] == selected_segment)]
    fig = px.bar(filtered_df, x='Açıklama', y='Ortalama Login', title='Login Counts by Description')
    return fig


app.run_server(mode='inline', port=8057) 


which returns

